# insert div for loop in div class

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically create some divs inside my html file with a for loop method and it's working fine, the problem is that I want to insert some of them in a class 1 and the others insert in class 2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body><script>    
        var array = ["name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6"];
        for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            var j=0;
            var newElement = document.createElement('div');
            
            newElement.id = array[i];
            newElement.className = "names";
           
            newElement.innerHTML = array[i];
            document.body.appendChild(newElement);
        }       
  </script></body>
  </html>
```

What should I do to insert for example the first 3 divs with name1,2,3 in a div class names1 and the others ( div with names 4,5,6 in a div class names2)

Comment: And how looks your HTML? Please add it.

Comment: This is the inscript inside the HTML. My HTML is empty, except this script.

Comment: It looks like all you need is some mathematics?

Comment: My problem is I dont know how to insert a specific div in a div class. For exemple I do a if condition i <= 3 do something.

Comment: @TudorStanciulescu, Look at the below solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add condition like,

```
if(i <= 2) {
   newElement.className = "names1"
 } else {
    newElement.className = "names2"
 }
```

Check if the index `i` is lesser or equal to `2` then add the [**className**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) `names1` else you could add the [**className**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) as `names2` .

And the snippet as follows,

```js
var array = ["name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6"];

for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  
   var newElement = document.createElement('div');
   newElement.id = array[i];
            
   if(i <= 2) {
      newElement.className = "names1"
    } else {
      newElement.className = "names2"
    }

     newElement.innerHTML = array[i];

     document.body.appendChild(newElement);

  }
```

**Edit:**

To split up the two div's and place them inline, you can use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method and make a wrapper div and iterate the `names-1` and `names-2` class and append to respective wrapper div and append both the wrapper div's to the DOM like,

```js
var array = ["name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6"];

const namesWrapper = document.createElement('div');
namesWrapper.className = "names-wrapper";

for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  
   var newElement = document.createElement('div');
   newElement.id = array[i];
            
   if(i <= 2) {
      newElement.className = "names1"
    } else {
      newElement.className = "names2"
    }

     newElement.innerHTML = array[i];

     namesWrapper.appendChild(newElement);

  }


const namesOne = namesWrapper.querySelectorAll('.names1');

const namesOneWrapper = document.createElement('div');
namesOneWrapper.className = "names1-wrapper";

namesOne.forEach((data) => {
  namesOneWrapper.append(data)
})

const namesTwo = namesWrapper.querySelectorAll('.names2');

const namesTwoWrapper = document.createElement('div');
namesTwoWrapper.className = "names2-wrapper";

namesTwo.forEach((data) => {
  namesTwoWrapper.append(data)
})

namesWrapper.append(namesOneWrapper);
namesWrapper.append(namesTwoWrapper);

document.body.append(namesWrapper)
```

```css
.names-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.names1-wrapper {
    margin: 10px;
}

.names2-wrapper {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thx for your answer, but this is not going to make me 3 class className1 and 3 class className2? Or it will be only 1 className1 and 1 className2?

Comment: Or let's say it's working, how do i put  both className1 and 2 inside other class Names? Because in HTML i need to display inline these 2 classes, 1 in left and 1 in right.

Comment: @TudorStanciulescu, Really your explanation is not clear.. I have provided what you ask in question..I couldn't understand your explanation..

Comment: You said that there are totally six divs aand for first three div there will be ```class="names1``` and for next three div there will be ```class="names2``` .. And it is what the above solution does.. What you need apart from this?

Comment: Ok, ok, i will try to be clear. So now, i have 2 classes. names1 and names2, right? I want to insert these 2 classes inside other class so i can display them inline

Comment: Anyway thx for your previous answer, It was greate and it's working, but know i want to insert these 2 divs classes, name1 and 2 inside other div class so I can display inline.

Comment: @TudorStanciulescu, I now see what you are seeing.. Here is the solution of what you wanted, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/LYZEOJj

Comment: @TudorStanciulescu, Also edited the above solution.. Please look into it..

Comment: Yes, Thx bro, That's what is was talking about. Thx, I ll check your answer and let you know if it's working. THX

Comment: @TudorStanciulescu, Sure.. Don't forget to accept the answer if it resolves your issue..

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. I will implement this method in my project. THX @Maniraj Murugan